# I want to find out the total buy and sell from the inventory for each product. But the problem is the status is in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
Select Pepsi,Coca,
Case If P_Name= 'Pepsi' And Status= 'Sell'
     Then (Sum(Quantity) Minus PB_Quantity)
     End Pepsi,
     
     If P_Name= 'CoCa' And Status= 'Sell'
     Then (Sum(Quantity) Minus CB_Quantity) 
     End Coca
from
(Select 
Case If P_Name= 'Pepsi' And Status= 'Buy'
     Then Sum(Quantity)
     End  PB_Quantity,
     
     If P_Name= 'CoCa' And Status= 'Buy'
     Then Sum(Quantity) 
     End CB_Quantity
     
     from Inventory)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `group by`?

```
select p_name, status, sum(quantity)
from t
group by p_name, status;
```

Or do you want the net amount?

```
select p_name,
       sum(case when status = 'sell' then quantity
                when status = 'buy' then - quantity
           end)
from t
group by p_name;
```

Comment: I have the status column that contains the Status either buy or sell for the product. Now I want to find the total amount of the specific product left in the inventory

Comment: @Eddie . . . I think that is what this query does, although it is possible that the sign is backward (I based on the logic on your query, but I think "buy"s should be subtracted from "sell"s in most circumstances).

Comment: "The problem is the status in in the same column" - ***Wrong***. The status must (well should anyway)  be in the same column where the db/row stated is differentiated its value. With a single column you need a simple list (check constraint perhaps) or table lookup (with FK) to validate, and a single column reference to access that provides a complete answer. Were it multiple columns you have a maintenance headache making sure only 1 column has value and validating each. Perhaps not so bad with 2, but suppose you had 20 or 200, or more.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ...hey! I have tried your both solutions first one is giving 50 in result and second one is showing empty column I have values for pepsi(bu)

Comment: @Eddie . . . They do different things.  I'm not clear which you want.